# Custom orderBy for nested objects in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, object, nested, sql-order-by, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm trying to order all my objects in my array by a nested property, in my case the `validUntil` field. I just can't figure out how to do this?

I'm using angular with a ng-repeat to loop over my objects. It would be great to extend this with a custom filter (so I can create multiple orderby fields)

I searched on SO but I didn't find any good solutions for this type of object structure.

**Update**
All the validUntil fields are epoch timestamps. So my output should be like ascending or descending on the validUntil field. Is this even possible? I think I need to break my checkin and fans objects apart and create a new array to achieve this?

```
[{
  "19852" : {
    "checkins" : {
      "-KJk_QqoIMQi_XT4V-e8" : {
        "called" : false,
        "createdAt" : 1465398937,
        "daysBetween" : 22,
        "new" : 2000,
        "old" : 996,
        "ratio" : 45.54545454545455,
        "type" : "checkins",
        "validUntil" : 1467324000
      }
    },
    "fans" : {
      "-KLL5pZsdZu2lAbmIuED" : {
        "called" : false,
        "createdAt" : 1467102227,
        "daysBetween" : 3,
        "new" : 500,
        "old" : 173,
        "ratio" : 109,
        "type" : "fans",
        "validUntil" : 1467324000
      },
      "-KLLqu_BT6cIVf-ALJMA" : {
        "called" : false,
        "createdAt" : 1467114826,
        "daysBetween" : 2,
        "new" : 600,
        "old" : 174,
        "ratio" : 213,
        "type" : "fans",
        "validUntil" : 1467324000
      }
    },
    "name" : "Test 1"
  },
  "-KCGLvKjmF0dxe8QuAXh" : {
    "checkins" : {
      "-KLRVY9FAzHDPTIf1_qS" : {
        "called" : false,
        "createdAt" : 1467209626,
        "daysBetween" : 32,
        "new" : 4000,
        "old" : 3699,
        "ratio" : 6.9,
        "type" : "checkins",
        "validUntil" : 1470002400
      }
    },
    "name" : "Test 2"
  },
  "-KKOX2JDkM84jrZcHHq4" : {
    "fans" : {
      "-KL253oeqDFedCRpDV4a" : {
        "called" : false,
        "createdAt" : 1466783256,
        "daysBetween" : 6,
        "new" : 10,
        "old" : 1,
        "ratio" : 1.5,
        "type" : "fans",
        "validUntil" : 1467324000
      }
    },
    "name" : "Test 3"
  }
}]
```

Comment: Can you please modify the question,  your requirement is not that clear? I mean can you please describe a bit more.

Comment: Are you trying to order by checkins, fans, or the minimum validUntil of either?

Comment: Most great would be to order by all validUntils over all objects (but I think you can't break them apart... Unless you'll create a new array)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AngularJs's OrderBy does not allow objects to be ordered.  To get around this, you can either convert the object to an array yourself or create a new filter to do this behind the scenes.

Here is how to do it via the custom filter.  Please note that the function getMinValue is recursive and does not handle circular references (they will keep spinning).  If you encounter that as an issue, you'll just need to modify this function to not recursively call on certain keys.

Here is the javascript code:

```
angular.module("myApp", []).filter('orderObjectBy', function(orderByFilter) {
  return function(items, sortPredicate, reverseOrder) {
    var array= [];
    angular.forEach(items, function(item) {
      array.push(item);
    });
    return orderByFilter(array, sortPredicate, reverseOrder);
  };
}).controller('someController', function ($scope) {
    $scope.order = function(obj){
        return getMinValue(obj);
    };
    function getMinValue(obj){
        //this is a recursive call that will look through all of the objects to find the minimum validUntil.  Be careful because circular references will loop forever.
        //if you believe you might have circular references, then there are small changes you can make to account for that.  It just didn't seem necessary for your code.
        var minValidUntil = null;
        angular.forEach(obj, function(item) {
            var validUntil = item.validUntil;
            if(validUntil == null && angular.isObject(item)){
                validUntil = getMinValue(item);
            }
            if(validUntil != null && (minValidUntil == null || validUntil < minValidUntil)){
                minValidUntil = validUntil;
            }
        });
        return minValidUntil;
    }
    $scope.data = {
      "19852" : {
        "checkins" : {
          "-KJk_QqoIMQi_XT4V-e8" : {
            "called" : false,
            "createdAt" : 1465398937,
            "daysBetween" : 22,
            "new" : 2000,
            "old" : 996,
            "ratio" : 45.54545454545455,
            "type" : "checkins",
            "validUntil" : 1467324000
          }
        },
        "fans" : {
          "-KLL5pZsdZu2lAbmIuED" : {
            "called" : false,
            "createdAt" : 1467102227,
            "daysBetween" : 3,
            "new" : 500,
            "old" : 173,
            "ratio" : 109,
            "type" : "fans",
            "validUntil" : 1467324000
          },
          "-KLLqu_BT6cIVf-ALJMA" : {
            "called" : false,
            "createdAt" : 1467114826,
            "daysBetween" : 2,
            "new" : 600,
            "old" : 174,
            "ratio" : 213,
            "type" : "fans",
            "validUntil" : 1467324000
          }
        },
        "name" : "Test 1"
      },
      "-KCGLvKjmF0dxe8QuAXh" : {
        "checkins" : {
          "-KLRVY9FAzHDPTIf1_qS" : {
            "called" : false,
            "createdAt" : 1467209626,
            "daysBetween" : 32,
            "new" : 4000,
            "old" : 3699,
            "ratio" : 6.9,
            "type" : "checkins",
            "validUntil" : 1470002400
          }
        },
        "name" : "Test 2"
      },
      "-KKOX2JDkM84jrZcHHq4" : {
        "fans" : {
          "-KL253oeqDFedCRpDV4a" : {
            "called" : false,
            "createdAt" : 1466783256,
            "daysBetween" : 6,
            "new" : 10,
            "old" : 1,
            "ratio" : 1.5,
            "type" : "fans",
            "validUntil" : 1467324000
          }
        },
        "name" : "Test 3"
      }
    };
});
```

Here is the html that I used for testing:

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="someController">
    <div ng-repeat='obj in data | orderObjectBy: order'>
        <span>{{obj.name}}</span>
        <div ng-repeat='checkin in obj.checkins'>
            <span>checkin - {{checkin.validUntil}}</span>
        </div>
        <div ng-repeat='fan in obj.fans'>
            <span>fan - {{fan.validUntil}}</span>
        </div>
        <br /><br />
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I ended up with pushing my objects to a new array for multiple filtering and ordering. Thanks for your help!